# Jquery .load each file in each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner with both Javascript and Jquery, I already managed to do this with a long javascript routine that iterates each element with attribute **"data-src"** then fetch attribute and use it to inject html in each element that has the attribute itself...

but when I try to make it easier with Jquery i get **undefined** in variable datasrc...
it works when i use a single element selector instead of $(this)

```
dataSrc = $(this).attr("data-src");
$( "[data-src]" ).load( languagePath + dataSrc );
```

I can't understand what's wrong because the syntax seems correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("[data-src]").each(function(){
    $(this).load( languagePath + $(this).attr('data-src') );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! works much faster than my javascript routine! (sorry can't vote because I've no reputation)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are actually trying to do is:

```
$.each($("[data-src]"), function(el) {
  var curr = $(el);
  curr.load( languagePath + curr.data('src'))

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply it works and it's really fast! my javascript code was horrible and slow! but even though your solution works i prefer the Charaf jra syntax. sorry can't vote (no reputation) :(